# Create a Favorite button that save state in localStorage using AngularJS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a favorite button for my AngularJS app. The idea is that when the user click the button the button image change to let the user know that It selected the album as favorite. I want to add that I am new to the framework and to web development in general, so any feedback and advice will be appreciated.

**This is the code for my Service:**

```
angular
.module("jeviteca")
.service("FavoriteService",[function(){


    //Favorites functions
    this.isLocalStorageEnable = function() {

        if(typeof (Storage) !== "undefined"){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    };

    this.isFavorite = function(scope){

        var fav = localStorage.getItem(scope.id);
        return fav === "1";
    };


    this.setFav = function(scope){
        localStorage.setItem(scope.id,"1");

    };


    this.deleteFav = function(scope){
        localStorage.removeItem(scope.id);

    };


}]);
```

**This is the directive I am ussing for it**

```
angular.module("jeviteca").directive("albumDirectiveTabla",    ["FavoriteService", function(FavoriteService) {

return {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "views/AlbumDirectiveTabla.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        model: "="
    },
    link: function(scope)
    {
        scope.isLocalStorageEnable = FavoriteService.isLocalStorageEnable;
        scope.isFavorite = FavoriteService.isFavorite(scope);
        scope.setFav = FavoriteService.setFav(scope);
        scope.deleteFav = FavoriteService.deleteFav(scope);

    }

};

}]);
```

**And this is my view --> .html**

```
<tr>
<td><img ng-src="vendor/resources/img/{{::model.image}}" width="50" height="50" class="img-circle"></td>
<td>{{::model.title}}</td>
<td>{{::model.year}}</td>
<td>{{::model.band.name}}</td>
<td>{{::model.genre.name}}</td>
<td>
   <ul>
       <li ng-hide="isLocalStorageEnable()"> Local Storage not enabled </li>
       <button ng-click="deleteFav()" ng-show="isFavorite()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></button>
       <button ng-click="setFav()" ng-hide="isFavorite()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></button>
   </ul>
</td>

<td ng-repeat="track in model.tracklist">
    <ul>
         <li>
          {{track}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please use the twitter-bootstrap tag. A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, i suggest you to user https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage it has fallback to cookies when localStorage is not available so you dont have to check if storage is enabled because it will be stored in cookies instead.

At second, with this architecutre angular doesnt know that something has changed.

```
 link: function(scope)
    {
          scope.isLocalStorageEnable = FavoriteService.isLocalStorageEnable;
          scope.isFavorite = FavoriteService.isFavorite(scope);

        scope.markAs = function(type) {
          switch(type) {
            case true :
              FavoriteService.setFav(scope);
              break;
            case true : 
              FavoriteService.deleteFav(scope);
              break;

          }
          scope.isFavorite = type;
        }

    }
```

Template

```
<button ng-click="markAs(!isFavorite)"  class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-heart' : isFavorite , 'glyphicon-heart-empty' : !isFavorite }"></button>
```

Let me know if its working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2hfVDt1DKhUiwNwyLBLT?p=preview

Comment: Still not working. I think the scope is undefined in the directive. Also, Why doy you have in the switch case the case true duplicated ?

Comment: Did you even checked if its undefined in console.log or chrome breakpoint? I created working plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/2hfVDt1DKhUiwNwyLBLT?p=preview

Comment: Got it, your solution works perfectly, I was having a probelm with the key used to store the data. +100